# Can threads access variables in a void?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I'm currently working on a game bot. It's a very simple bot, but I want to split it up into threads called. Move, search, click. If we have a int y in the thread search with a value of 900 can we get this integers value in click? Please include a code sample also if that's possible.

Comment: here's my code for it I'm at school writing this so its not compiled yet.

Comment: I've I turned the functions into threads but it seems They can't access the information. Also for some reason the code format doesn't work I guess I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Re, "Please include a code sample."  You first!  Please include a sample of _your_ code, tell us what you want it to do differently from what it does now, and maybe somebody will be able to help you out.

Comment: Re, "I want to split it up into threads called. Move, search, click"  Those are unusual names for threads.  I often find the most important thing to say about a thread is, what does it _wait_ for?  A pool worker waits for tasks to appear in a queue, and when it gets one it performs the task.  A server thread waits for incoming connections from clients, and when it gets one, it creates a new task or a new thread to represent the client.  What would your "Move" thread wait for?  What would your "search" or your "click" thread wait for?  And how will it help for those to be different threads?

Comment: Thanks for the advice I have never done anything like that.